# Sorting items in a MySQL database based on the order of another column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that looks something like this

```
Title     |     ID
---------------------------------
Hello           45
Hi              23
Yo              52
Test            76
```

And then I have another table that looks like this:

```
List                 |   Order
---------------------------------
Main List                76,23,45,52
```

What I want to do is query the database and output the title of the first table based on the order of the 2nd table.

Any ideas on the best way to do something like this?

Comment: Can you tell us how and what the Order is being based upon? - Maybe there is a simpler way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
    menu m
    INNER JOIN links l ON (l.menu_id = m.menu_id)
WHERE
    m.menu_id = 123
ORDER BY
    FIND_IN_SET(l.link_id, m.menu_order)
```

Obviously you'll need to change to reflect your actual table and column names

Per Michael Berkowski in the comments below, if you don't have a link between the two tables (so you can't join), you can accomplish the same with just:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(ID, (SELECT `Order` FROM t2))
```

Feel free to mess around with his SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/947e3/2

Thanks, Michael

Comment: Is a sub-select really any more efficient?

Comment: I didn't say it's more efficient. Point is in the OP's data there _is no_ link between the two tables, so you need to select only the first row's value. You could use a cartesian join too, but the OPs sample table has no evidence of a `l.menu_id`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Fair, but it also doesn't have actual table names - so I assumed other information was omitted to simplify the question. The important part of the answer anyway was that `FIND_IN_SET` will accomplish the task, but I will update the answer to be clear of this.

Comment: This looks close to what I'm trying to do but I can't figure out how to specify which list to use (their could be multiple lists).  In this case I want to order by the Sort order of the "Main List"

Comment: Do you know the ID for "Main List"? If so, just use: `FIND_IN_SET(ID, (SELECT \`Order\` FROM t2 WHERE Id = 123))`